# How to plot duplicates legends in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe with duplicated legends (yLabels) and each of them with a different value (yValues). The problem is that when I plot this dataframe using Matplotlib, all the duplicated legends are grouped - and this is not my intention. I have to show duplicated legends, each of them with its specific value.

How can I do this?

## CODE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


while True:

    yLabels = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'] ### these must appear 3x in the legends
    yValues = [-0.15, 0.00, 0.23]

    df=pd.DataFrame({'x': yLabels, 'Goal': [0,0,0], 'y': yValues})

    plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
    for column in df.drop('x', axis=1):
    plt.plot(df['x'], df[column], marker='', color='grey', linewidth=2, alpha=0.4)
    plt.plot(df['x'], df['Goal'], marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
    plt.xlim(-0.5,3)
num=0
    for i in df.values[2][1:]:
        num+=1
        name=list(df)[num]
    plt.text(10.2, df.Goal.tail(1), 'Goal', horizontalalignment='left', size='small', color='orange')
    plt.title("Distance between the Goal and the Actual Rates differences", loc='left', fontsize=12, fontweight=0, color='orange')
    plt.xlabel("Shipments")
    plt.ylabel("Variation")

    plt.pause(5)
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
```

Thank you

Comment: you code does not show any legend. What's your expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang I have added the legends as examples.

Comment: your code doesnt work

Comment: @Sheldore Sorry. I couldn't post the whole thing here, so now I have the code and it works.

Comment: The indentation is broken. Fix all these problems

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are looking for something like this:

```
yLabels = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'] ### these must appear 3x in the legends
yValues = [-0.15, 0.00, 0.23]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': yLabels, 
                   'Goal': [0, 0, 0], 
                   'y': yValues})

plt.scatter(df.index, df["y"])
plt.xticks(df.index, df["x"])
plt.show()
```

Here, I have used the row index as the data point location along the x axis, and have labeled them with the `df["x"]` column.

[image: Very unformatted matplotlib plot]

See also: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html